# Nginx Proxy Manager does not report correct client IP in logs

Tags: nginx, networking, docker, ip

I am new to networking and ran into an issue where the nginx proxy manager logs (proxy-host-*_access.log) report "[Client 172.19.0.1]" for all traffic making it useless in identifying who is connecting to my server.

my container is deployed with this compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    # network_mode: "host" #when used the link to the database breaks
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '2052:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '2053:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '91:81' # Admin Web Port
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose
      # - '21:21' # FTP
    environment:
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "xxx"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "xxx"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "xxx"
      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host
      # DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: alpine_mariadb
    image: 'yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_USER: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

The setup is as follows:

client(external internet) -> Cloudflare -> Router(port forward) -> Docker Network(172.19.0.1) -> Nginx Proxy manager container(172.19.0.3)

So far I tried editing the nginx.conf:

```
        # Real IP Determination
        # cloudflare IPs
        set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
        set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
        set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
        set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
        set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
        set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
        set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
        set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;

        #real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        # Local subnets:
        set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
        set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/12; # Includes Docker subnet
        # NGINX proxy docker bridge (172.19.0.1):
        set_real_ip_from 172.19.0.0/24;
        set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/16;
        # NPM generated CDN ip ranges:
        include conf.d/include/ip_ranges.conf;
        # always put the following 2 lines after ip subnets:
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
        real_ip_recursive on;
```

I also checked the container logs after restart in portainer and there are no errors (after fixing a few missing ";"), so I have no idea what to do.